# How to extract subtitles from MP4 and MKV movies

Tags: macos, mp4, subtitles, matroska, mp4box

I'm trying to extract subtitles from MP4 and MKV movies. I'm using mp4box (on OS X) but cannot figure out how it works.

Any hints?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

### MP4 and 3GP files

The free and cross-platform [MP4Box](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/wiki/MP4Box) only works with MP4 or 3GP containers. You can install it from the homepage. First, you want look at the different tracks and see which ID belongs to the subtitle track.

```
MP4Box -info input.mp4
```

Look at the ID next to the subtitle track. Then, based on the track ID `<trackId>` you want to extract, call the following command:

```
MP4Box -raw <trackID> input.mp4
```

Or, to export to the commonly used SRT format:

```
MP4Box -srt <trackID> input.mp4
```

---

### MKV files

In order to extract subtitles from Matroska (MKV) files, you need the free and open source [**`mkvtoolnix`**](https://web.archive.org/web/20151105204525/https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/) packages. They come for Windows and Linux, and on a Mac you can install them through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) with `brew install mkvtoolnix`.

Then, inspect the file:

```
mkvmerge -i input.mkv
```

This will list the tracks, for example like this:

```
File 'input.mkv': container: Matroska
Track ID 1: video (V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC)
Track ID 2: audio (A_AAC)
Track ID 3: subtitles (S_TEXT/UTF8)
```

Based on the ID of the track, call the following command, where `<trackID>` is the one you identified above. `<output>` is just a dummy name, you can use any you want.

```
mkvextract tracks input.mkv <trackID>:<output>.srt
```

So, in our case, that would have been:

```
mkvextract tracks input.mkv 3:subs.srt
```

Comment: This all works for linux too. I found `MP4Box` in the `gpac` package available via apt-get

Comment: To get `MP4Box` in Arch Linux, you need to install `gpac` from the community repo.

Comment: You can also get `gpac` for Mac via brew: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gpac. Tried and worked fine.

Answer (score 38):

Here is a solution for virtually any file format that is supported by `ffmpeg` (even remote files are supported):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 subtitle.srt
```

`ffmpeg` is present in newer Ubuntu versions by default, for Mac OS X and Windows you'll have to install it (by [downloading it from official web site](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) or via homebrew).

Here `video.mp4` is source local or remote video file name, and `subtitle.srt` is output subtitle file name. It is important to specify file extension for output, since `ffmpeg` detects what exactly you want to extract by it. That is, you can specify `.mp3` file extension in order to extract mp3 audio from video file, or just set another video container in order to convert between formats.