# How can I extract SRT subtitles from (MKV) video's?

Tags: video, subtitles, extract

I read that MKVToolNix will allow you to extract .SRT subtitles from .MKV videos. I'm using gMKVExtractGUI (v1.8.0.0) with MKVToolNix, but as the screenshot below shows it will only extract .ASS files. [This answer to a related question](https://superuser.com/a/393771/453919) suggests that using the .SRT extension in the CLI version will create a .SRT file, but it's just the same .ASS file with the different extension.

[image]

How can I create .SRT files from .MKV (and preferably also other) videos?

Comment: Use an ass2srt converter. https://lab.sorz.org/tools/asstosrt/?lang=en

Comment: Thanks @IporSircer. That works, but I'd like to have a one-step solution.

Comment: Then search for a gui which has builtin ass2srt converter, or write a script yourself.

Comment: As noted in comments, the online converter has a bug: `0:08:11.34` gets converted to `00:08:11,034` instead of the correct `00:08:11,340`.